# How many characters can a javascript session hold?

Tags: javascript, session

Basically what is says in the title.

console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("session");

Comment: @trincot So it's 5MB per domain, not 5MB per variable?

Comment: It does not matter how many keys you store. It is the combined volume that counts.

Comment: @trincot What if it's on 2 different tabs? Is it 5MB per tab?

Comment: The question is: is it the same session? That depends on how the tab or window was opened. This can be browser specific.

Comment: @trincot Anyways, 5MB is enough to store 5 million characters, right? That's more than enough for anything.